# Multiple Packages from Same Source

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a codebase consisting of `spam.PartA`, `spam.PartB`, and `spam.Common`. How do I write `setup.py` to create packages for `PartA + Common` and `PartB + Common`?

Comment: Maybe create three independent packages, and let PartA and PartB have Common as a dependency?